# Removing rectangle line in DEM

Tags: raster, qgis-3, dem

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftyMN.png)I have downloaded Aster dem file. One of my dem file has rectangle line.
Does any body know how to remove it? I am using QGIS 3.4.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not displaying two different layers here?  Maybe you have two layers showing and one is using transparency?

Comment: No merge, smallest tile of  17 rasters, all of  them are exact same size. not using transparency.

Comment: What happens when you display this raster as a hillshade?

Comment: still the same line appears as it was in dem.

Comment: Is this ASTER GDEM v3? Too bad...

Comment: You are right !  kazuhito